# Sidebar won't be edited in any themes in WordPress: "The editor has encountered an unexpected error"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Getting below error while editing side bar in Mismo theme (but can't edit side bar on any theme due to below error,

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H59f.png)

I tried below-

Switched to a different theme
Wordpress was upgraded to latest version
discarded plugins- Yoast SEO, WooCommerce, Jetpack, Classic Editor etc.

Comment: Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: To get a better error output it's always a good idea to set `WP_DEBUG` to true in this case. This way you get a more meaningful error message that you can work with to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody could answer, I found the solution myself.

The problem was with theme editor loading theme widgets.

I simply installed classic widget extension- https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/classic-widgets/ and the problem was resolved.